# printing from an array?

Tags: java, eclipse

Im quite new to database connection i want to ask a question regarding java.
how do i print the array list in this code ?

```
public String[] getList(String listname){
    try{
        ResultSet rs;
        rs=sta.executeQuery("Select * from book;");
        rs.next();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
        rs=sta.executeQuery("Select * from book;");
        String[] tobeout = new String[count];
        for(int x=0;rs.next();x++){
            tobeout[x]=rs.getString(1);
        }
        return tobeout;
    }catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();return null;}
}
```

what to do i write in my tester class so i can print the array ( after the query ) .can anyone please help me . thank you

note : MyListBackEnd is the name of the class which contains the query"getList" method.
here is what i added so far in my tester class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {




    MyListBackEnd en =  new MyListBackEnd();
    en.getList("book");
    System.out.println(en.tobeout[1]);
    en.close();
}
```

}

but it has a error on the System.out.print.

Comment: as in System.out.println() ???

Comment: Have you tried `for (String s : getList("some name") System.out.println(s);`?

Comment: i have updated my question with my post so far :)

Comment: tobeout[] can be empty... throwing an error on en.tobeout[1]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to simply print out your `tobeout` `String[]` once populated, you can use the `java.util.Arrays`' static method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tobeout));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply modifying loop.

```
 for(int x=0;rs.next();x++){
            tobeout[x]=rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(tobeout[x]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your main method like this:

```
String[] bookList = en.getList("book");
for (int i=0; i<bookList.length; i++){
    System.out.println(bookList[i]);
}
```

You have made two mistakes:
1st mistake: `en.getList("book");` You haven't save list which method `getList("book")` returned.

2nd mistake: If you want print array you mast iterate through all array elements, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < ARRAY.length; i++){
```

Comment: what do you mean by " save list which method getList("book") returned " ?

Comment: @user3410855 Result of execution method `getList()` is string array. That array is returned with `return tobeout;` in method `getList()`. If you don't catch result of execution in main method you couldn't display result.

Comment: @user3410855 I have changed my answer: In main method I renamed variable `tobeout` to `bookList`. In `bookList` you save result which return `getList()`.